# Send data to the server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I recently perform some ajax request on my website but I'm still beginner.

Here is a stupid question: How to send (POST) a data to the server without waiting any response ?

In all the example I found on internet, the ajax call is used to reload a part of the page. It work perfectly, but my idea here is just to send a data that could be store in DB for example without waiting any response.

I'm using Zend framework with MVC pattern. I tried something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'/controller/action',
    data: { myDataToPost: aData },

        success:function(response){
        },
        failure:function(){
         alert('Could not save your entry');
        }
});
```

It works fine if I define an action in my controller but I can see in firebug an 404 error on controller/action page. For sure it doesn't exist because i don't want any response...

Many thanks for your help!
Cedric.

Comment: `failure` is not a valid ajax setting.

Comment: update: the controller/action exist (i can do some stuff on it) but the corresponding view doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

"Here is a stupid question: How to send (POST) a data to the server without waiting any response ?"

```
$.ajax({
     timeout: 1
});
```

Set the request `timeout` to 1 millisecond (zero doesn't work), thus giving the `xmlHttpRequest` 1 millisecond to complete (go to server, process request, return response, which is virtually impossible), otherwise mark it as timed out (failed).

Comment: Don't understand you there... in your example, what data are you sending to the server ?

Comment: What difference does it make what data or what url I send? It is proof of concept, and there are default ajax settings that jQuery uses.

Comment: imagine you got an html list, when the user clic on an item a javascript is called that can POST using Ajax the value of the item selected to the server... And you want to store in DB the value of the selected item. How can you do such stuff ?

Comment: Your question should be "How do I use ajax?". I suggest googling it. As for your original question, this correctly answers it.

Comment: I'm using ajax... For example I'm able to fill/load a specific part of my view with an item selected in DB indexed by an Id corresponding to the selected list item. In this case, the purpose of my ajax call is to fill a part of my view. I suppose I do it well, But imagine I don't what the response.... Arg. :-S sorry but I don't get it

Comment: function getItemDetail(aId){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'/item/detail/format/html',
        data: { id: aId },
        beforeSend:function(response){
            $('#divItemDetail').html('Loading...');
        },
        success:function(response){
            $('#divItemDetail').html(response);
        },
        failure:function(){
            alert('Echec de requette ajax');
        }
});

Comment: But that's not what I want in my case... I don't want any response. Don't want to fill any part of my view with the response. I just want to post a data to the server.

Comment: Actually the question could be, is it possible to send an HTTP query without waiting for an HTTP response...